# How do I end a loop within a loop after 10 seconds?

Tags: python, opencv, datetime

I am working with opencv and instead of using the typical while loop on a video I am running an extra while loop inside for other functions. My goal is for the second while loop after activated to end and break all the loops after 10 seconds.

So far I used `datetime` to create a `time_start` variable and then tried to find the change of time with the `time_delta` variable and the while loop should break after it reaches a value of 10. I only have a couple weeks of python experience so I am probably making a simple mistake. Here is the code I am trying to execute (you can ignore the 'MAIN FUNCTIONS' code):

```
start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
end_time = 0

while end_time < datetime.datetime.now():

    ret, frame = cap.read( )

    if point1 and point2:

        end_time =start_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)

        if has_run == 0:
            gray_get()
            has_run = 1


        ######### MAIN FUNCTIONS ######################################
        cv2.rectangle(frame, point1, point2, (0, 0, 0), 2)
        first_frame_roi = first_frame[point1[1]:point2[1], point1[0]:point2[0]]
        cropped_window = frame[point1[1]:point2[1], point1[0]:point2[0], :]
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(cropped_window, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prev_gray, gray, None,.5, 6, 15, 3, 5, 1.1, 0)
        prev_gray = gray
        mag, ang = cv2.cartToPolar(flow[..., 0], flow[..., 1])
        mag_list.append(mag)
        cv2.imshow('optical flow', draw_flow(gray, flow))
        #################################################################

    cv2.imshow('Original', frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if key == 27:
         break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Try to add ```time_delta.total_seconds() < 10``` in while loop as ```while time_delta.total_seconds() < 10:```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the error ```'int' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'```

Comment: You can use `datetime` module to implement your while loop, check my answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of running a while loop for 10 seconds is using `datetime` module.

```
import datetime

start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
#end time is 10 sec after the current time
end_time = start_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)

#Run the loop till current time exceeds end time
while end_time > datetime.datetime.now():
    #do stuff
```

An advantage here is you can also define time intervals in minutes and hours using the [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) function

Comment: I tried to implement your code (edited in main post) but I may be using it wrong, I would like the timer to start after the ```if point1 and point2: ``` statement is fulfilled and then have the while loop end.

Comment: Then put the while loop within the if condition!

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
endTime_s = time.time() + 10.0
while time.time() < endTime_s:
    doStuff()
```